# rails: What are the consequences of a leaked secret_key_base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, github, secret-key

In rails we have something called secret_key_base in `config/secrets.yml`

What if this production secret is accidentally shared via GitHub (public repo)

What's the worst thing a hacker can do?
Can salted passwords in the users table leak as a result...

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails by default uses browser cookies as its session store. This means that as opposed to the traditional way of storing session data on the server and only a session id in the cookie, Rails stores the whole session data in the cookie.

This of course would not be very secure in many cases, any user could just see and modify his session contents. So the cookie in Rails is encrypted and signed. The key used for this (encryption and integrity verification) is in `secret_key_base`.

What this practically means is if this `secret_key_base` is compromised, any user can decrypt, modify and reencrypt his session cookie (all the data in the session). In some applications this causes no problem as there is nothing interesting stored in the session anyway. But in most cases, it leads to all kinds of problems depending on the actual business logic. For example if privileges were stored in the session, a user could change his privileges in the application, probably an unintended result.

Note that if you use a different session store (like for example Redis), you don't need this secret. Afaik it's only used to encrypt cookies if the cookie store is used for sessions. Using a server-side session store is a good idea and the best practice anyway as it is more secure.

Comment: With regards to server-side stores and their cookies: even if the session data is in (e.g.) Redis, the cookie or token issued to the client will have an ID that links it to the server-side session. You either need to ensure those IDs are sufficiently long (32 bytes) & random (using Ruby's `SecureRandom` gem) or if you are using any other identifier (like a literal userID or name), using a HMAC with `secret_key_base` to sign/verify the value to prevent tampering/forgery.

Comment: Exactly, but that's an orthogonal problem. Session ids must be securely generated of course, and in most cases that does not involve `secret_key_base`. But if it does somehow, then the same applies, you have to change it asap if compromised.